# problema al mostrar div inicialmente hidden con show() JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Tengo un div encima de un map de google el cual quiero que al cargar la página se encuentre oculto, mediante la propiedad 'visibility: hidden', el problema es que cuando intento mostrarlo con el siguiente código no funciona, funcionandome para mostrarlo y ocultarlo por el contrario si la propiedad incial es 'visibility: visible' , ¿Dónde puede estar el fallo?

Asi es como intento mostrarlo pero al clickar no hace nada:

css

```
 #menuMap{
         visibility: hidden;
          position: absolute;
          width: 30%;
          height: 100%;
          padding-top: 70px;
          right: 0;
         display: inline-block;
         background-color: white;
      }
```

Y así como lo intento mostrar:

```
 marker.addListener("click", () => {
            
            var divIsHide;
            divIsHide = $('#menuMap').is(':hidden');
            
            if (divIsHide){
                $('#menuMap').show(1000);
        
                 
                
            }else{
                 $('#menuMap').hide(1000);
                
            }  
              
        });
```

Pero si por el contrario muestro el div inicialmente y mediante el click en el punto del mapa lo oculto primero, esto funciona perfectamente ocultando y mostrando el menu, pero quiero que inicialmente este oculto. Gracias

css

```
 #menuMap{
         visibility: visible;
          position: absolute;
          width: 30%;
          height: 100%;
          padding-top: 70px;
          right: 0;
         display: inline-block;
         background-color: white;
      }
```

Y así como lo intento mostrar:

```
 marker.addListener("click", () => {
            
            var divIsVisible;
            divIsVisible = $('#menuMap').is(':visible');
            
            if (divIsVisible){
                $('#menuMap').hide(1000);
        
                 
                
            }else{
                 $('#menuMap').show(1000);
                
            }  
              
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery usa `display:none` en el método [`hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) tal como puedes ver en su documentación. Tú le estás poniendo por defecto a tu elemento `visibility: hidden`.

Para solucionarlo, modifica tu css para que el `display` sea `none`:

```
#menuMap{
         display: none;
         position: absolute;
         width: 30%;
         height: 100%;
         padding-top: 70px;
         right: 0;
         display: inline-block;
         background-color: white;
      }
```

Espero que te funcione correctamente ahora.

Comment: El valor none es de la propiedad display no visibility, modifique la propiedad a none y la compare en el click, modificandolá despues a display:inline-block, y  conseguí el efecto deseado, modifica en el código lo de visibility y display para aceptar tu respuesta, Gracias

Comment: Con las prisas pasa lo que pasa, ya lo cambié, un saludo.